# MariaDB : create database and execute sql script without '<' character from the command line cmd.exe

Tags: sql, powershell, command-line, mariadb, datasource

I'm trying in every way to create a database and populate it with sql script from the command line.

```
mysql --user=root --password=hello --execute=create database test --source='accounts.sql'
-> starts to print help

mysql --user=root --password=hello --execute='create database test' --source='accounts.sql'
-> starts to print help
```

or the only database:

```
mysql --user=root --password=hello --execute=create database test
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'test'
```

I'm going to manage it through powershell but before to do it I want to be sure it works from mariaDB command line. (Powershell doesn't recognize '<' character).

Is it possible create db and populate it from command line ?
Thank to all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The preferrable way to open and populate a database with PowerShell would be to first jump to the mysql command prompt:

```
    mysql -u {username} -p
```

Then enter your password. In the mysql CLI, open the database with the following commands:

```
    use {databasename};
    source {path_to_your_file.sql};
```

If you have to create the database first, do the following:

```
    create database {databasename};
    use {databasename};
    source {path_to_your_file.sql};
```

Or if you prefer oneliners:

```
   mysql -u{username} -p{password}; create database {databasename}; use {databasename}; source {path_to_your_file.sql};
```

Comment: Thanks but I mean from the command com line, sry it's my fault. mysql --user=root --password=hello; create database test00; use test00;   It returns the help text

Comment: Try this: `mysql --user=root --password=hello --execute='create database test00; use test00; source path.sql'`

Comment: I discovered we have to use quotation mark------>  mysql --user=root --password=hello --execute="create database test00; use test00;"  .it works but  Source still return an error (You have an error in your SQL syntax;etc..) , i'm trying again

Comment: mysql --user=root --password=hello --execute="create database test00; use test00;Source accounts.sql;"  <-- Works ! Thx Dave. We need replace ' with quotation mark

Comment: Great! It worked with single quotation marks for me though, so no idea why you have to use double quotes instead. Great that it works now!

Comment: mind that you have to use a path that doesn't include any white space